# "Verify it's you/Purchase Authentication" issue with Google Play

Tags: google-play-store

For 2 weeks, I came across an issue. When I try to buy something with Google Play, it tells me that I need to enter a 5-digit code which I get by SMS on my phone. After that, it sends me on a similar screen which says "Verify it's you/Purchase Authentication" as you see in the picture I posted.

[image]

I tried everything, passwords, that 5-digit code that I got earlier, card info, etc. I honestly don't know what to do since I couldn't find any info about this issue. The problem isn't just on my phone but on the emulator too.

Additional info:

- [`adb shell dumpsys activity activities`](https://pastebin.com/KMk9N2QS)
- [`adb shell dumpsys window windows`](https://pastebin.com/v6mJiPuE)

What do I need to put in that blank space?

Comment: That screen looks very suspicious. I am very sure that it does not belong to Android or any Google service/app. Therefore I see two possibilities: 1. On your device some administrative software is installed that prevents you from buying something in Play Store. 2. The screen is generated by a malicious app and is some sort of phishing attack. All entered passwords may have been sent to the malware backend.

Comment: Hi, recently there's another facing [the same problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/236575/44325), and based on their info, they live in Romania and using Vodafone mobile carrier. If you're okay with sharing some info for pinpointing the issue, could you also mention the country, the mobile carrier, and [your Google Play's current payment method](https://play.google.com/store/paymentmethods)?