# "Verify it's you" pop-up when I try to make a purchase through Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, google, in-app-purchase

Whenever I want to make an in-app purchase, a prompt with the header "Verify it's you" with a text box and a submit button appears, but it doesn't say what i need to introduce in the text box. I tried my password, security codes etc, but it doesn't work. I couldn't take a screenshot due to security. Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this unanswered question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/234262/44325). What is your device model and if you're okay with sharing it, the mobile carrier, the country where you live, and if you have some payments linked to the Google account? Most of us haven't experienced this, so it's hard for us to answer.

Comment: Typically a "Verify it's you" dialog from Google looks like shown in this question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184927

Comment: May be this dialog is created by the Sim-toolkit (would be an explanation why the dialog is so simple)? This would make sense if GooglePlay Store is trying to charge the payment via your mobile network carrier.

Comment: this usually happens when your google account is used on other devices

Comment: @Andrew T. yes that one but I don't have the "Resend code" button. I have a Samsung Galaxy S20+ serial number:R58N93LAYYL carrier Vodafone country Romania

Comment: Also transactions worked like a month ago.

Comment: Appreciate the clarification. By "payments linked to the Google account", it was supposed to be "payment *methods*", not "transactions" (sorry, my bad). From [Google Play's Payment methods](https://play.google.com/store/paymentmethods), is there anything related to your mobile carrier, or probably something else other than cards? Just like Robert, I also have a suspicion that this may be related to "direct carrier billing". If that's the case, perhaps you can try contacting customer service about this? Otherwise, what is your current payment method?

Comment: Nope other than my credit card I don't have another payment method